# Flutter - I can't fill the screen when I hide the system bars

Tags: flutter

I can't fill the screen with Container when I hide the system bars; I have an appbar too...
I need that green fills to bottom, instead I have that white bar

```
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
  primary: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    primary: false,
  ),
 child: Container(
   color: Colors.green, 
   constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
 )
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try adding a background color to the Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding green as `backgroundColor` to the `Scaffold`

and also try this:
1) import

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

2) and add this code to the main widget tree :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.green, //for the statusbar.
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.green, // for the nav bar
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // as you need dark or light
    ));

return MaterialApp(home: yourHomeWidgetWhereTheScaffoldIsDefined....
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I need a Container because I set the decoration to put a background image

Comment: Do you mean to say that the green colour refers to the area that the image will fill?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding to scaffold: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false

```
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false //Add this line
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
      primary: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        primary: false,
      ),
     child: Container(
       color: Colors.green, 
       constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
     )
```